# AngularJS ng-include does not include view unless passed in $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Is it wrong to assume that `ngInclude` can take a raw path?  I keep trying to set my `ngInclude` as follows:

```
<div ng-include src="views/header.html"></div>
```

This does not work but if I do something like this it does work.

```
// HeaderController
app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.templates = {[
     template: { url: 'views/header.html' }
   ]};

   $scope.template = $scope.templates[0].template;
});
```

In my index.html

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
  <div ng-include src="template.url"></div>
</div>
```

Does `ngInclude` only except values off of the scope?  If so why is it this way and not a straight include of the html partial.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

[`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) accepts an expression.
If you want to specify the explicit URL directly in there, you have to give a string.

```
<div ng-include src="'page.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Yea just saw that.  Examples that I were looking at were using an older version of angular.

Comment: Spent a lot of time this afternoon trying to figure this one out. Of *course* it needs to be a string. That makes *complete* sense.

Comment: doesn't work with ngSanitize enabled in the app module. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: One more thing: The page can not have underscores as filename.

Comment: @muffin can you elaborate? My filenames have plenty of underscores in them and work fine.

Comment: Well, I have lost like one hour because of the damn underscore in the filename! It's strange. I have checked again and if my view has underscore as filename then it wont appear! the value for src attribute is retrieved from the scope!

Comment: Small single quotes solve the problem. I could not see exact change(My poor eye). Please mention add single quotes inside the double quotes in words.

Comment: For people who may be finding this answer for newer versions of Angular...the `src` attribute is only applicable if you are using `ng-include` as an element, e.g. `<ng-include src="'whatever.html'"></ng-include>`. If you are using it as an attribute then you shouldn't use the `src` attribute, e.g. `<div ng-include="'whatever.html'"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

[`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), as other directives ([`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) ...) **evaluates an Angular expression** from the scope. Without quotes (`''`), it will search for a variable of the scope.

---

Note that you don't have to specify the `src` attribute.

```
<div ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

Can be rewritted to: *(that is simpler)*

```
<div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

---

You can also use ng-include as an **element**:

```
<ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></ng-include>
```